# Python, define functions to generate multiple txt files tracked from task manager program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, io

I have a task that requires functions to read, write and display information, from and to *.txt* files.
I have completed the fist part of the code.

I am struggling to figure out this part of the question:

**1.** Add an option to generate reports to the main menu of the application.
The menu for the admin user should now look like this:

```
Please select on of the following options:  
r - register user  
a - add task  
va- view all tasks  
vm - view my tasks  
gr - generate reports  
ds - display statistics  
e - exit
```

***I have crated the above menu***

**2.** When the user chooses to generate reports, two text files, called **task_overview.txt** and **user_overview.txt**, should be generated. Both these text files should output data in a user-friendly, easy to read manner.

2.1 **task_overview.txt** should contain:
The total number of tasks that have been generated and tracked using the **task manager**.
The total number of completed tasks.
The total number of uncompleted tasks.
The total number of tasks that haven’t been completed and that are overdue.
The percentage of tasks that are incomplete.
The percentage of tasks that are overdue.

2.2 **user_overview.txt** should contain:
The total number of users registered with **task manager**.
The total number of tasks that have been generated and tracked using the **task manager**.

*For each user also describe:*
The total number of tasks assigned to that user.
What percentage of the total number of tasks have been assigned to that user?
What percentage of the tasks assigned to that user have been completed?
What percentage of the tasks assigned to that user must still be completed?
What percentage of the tasks assigned to that user have not yet been completed and are overdue?

**3.** Modify the menu option that allows the admin to display statistics so that the reports generated are read from **task_overview.txt** and **user_overview.txt** and displayed on the screen in a user-friendly manner.

**Any guidance will be much apricated**

Here is my **task manager** code thus far:
**Please see** *def reports():* **and** *def statistics():* **in code**

**UPDATE:** shortened the amount of code from the original post, as advised by "RolvApneseth"

```py
    def reports():   # NOTE: these are the functions I need help with please.
    
        return
    
    def statistics():   # NOTE: these are the functions I need help with please.
    
        return


    def displayMenu_Admin():
    
        global menu_input
    
        menu_input = input("""
    Please enter one of the following options:
    r - register user
    a - add task
    va- view all tasks
    vm - view my tasks
    gr - generate reports
    ds - display statistics
    e - exit
    """)

    if menu_input == "r":
        register()
    elif menu_input == "a":
        add_task()
    elif menu_input == "va":
        view_all()
    elif menu_input == "vm":
        view_more()
    elif menu_input == "gr":
        reports()
    elif menu_input == "ds":
        statistics() 
    elif menu_input == "e":
        exit()

    return menu_input


    #A menu should be displayed once the user has successfully logged in.
    
    def displayMenu():
    
        global menu_input
    
        menu_input = input("""
    Please enter one of the following options:
    a - add task
    va- view all tasks
    vm - view my tasks
    e - exit
    """)
    
        if menu_input == "a":
            add_task()
        elif menu_input == "va":
            view_all()
        elif menu_input == "vm":
            view_more()
        elif menu_input == "e":
            exit()
    
        return menu_input

    
    def login():
    
        username = input("Please enter your username?:\n")
        password = input("Please enter your password?:\n")
    
        for line in open("user.txt","r").readlines():
            field = line.strip().split(", ")
            if username == field[0] and password == field[1]:
                print("Hello " + username + ", welcome back!\n")
                return True, field[0]== "admin"
    
        return False, False
    
    login_success, is_admin = login()
    
    if login_success and is_admin:
       displayMenu_Admin()
    elif login_success:
       displayMenu()
    else:
       print("Username or Password Incorrect\n")
```

Comment: This is a lot of code and a lot of text friend, you should post something shorter with just the relevant information to the specific problem you need help with imo

Comment: Also have you used classes before? If you know how to use classes, using a class here would make things easier, no need for global statements

Comment: @RolvApneseth, I just thought to use my entire code to show what I have done. I will shorten it now.

I am yet to use classes, still in the beginning stage of defining my own functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to change some parts of my original code, but eventually and with a little help, I got the answers to the functions I was looking for...
Hope this helps someone else in the future!

```py
# Displaying only admin specific statistics to the screen.
def display_admin_stats():

    # exists(), it says that there are specific cases in which a file or folder exists but,
    # 'os.path.exists()' returns false: Return True if path refers to an existing path or an open file descriptor.
    if not os.path.exists('task_overview.txt') and not os.path.exists('user_overview.txt'):

        generate_task_overview() # Calls the function that generates 'task_overview.txt'.
        generate_user_overview() # Calls the function that generates 'user_overview.txt'.
    
    print("Displaying statistics for admin:\n")
    user_dictionary = user_dict()
    task_dictionary = task_dict()
    
    print(f"Total number of tasks: {len(task_dictionary)}")
    print(f"Total number of users: {len(user_dictionary)}")
            
    with open('task_overview.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as task:
        print('\nTASK OVERVIEW STATS:\n')
        for line in task:
            print(line.strip())
        
    with open('user_overview.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as task:
        print('\nUSER OVERVIEW STATS:\n')
        for line in task:
            print(line.strip())
            
    exit_menu()

# Generate the task overview text file.
def generate_task_overview():
    task_dictionary = task_dict()
    completed_tasks = 0
    uncompleted_tasks = 0
    overdue_tasks = 0
    
    # Open the file, or creates it if it doesn't exist.
    # Reads each task from the task_dict function.
    # And applies the logic to write to the file.
    with open('task_overview.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as task_overview:
        for count in task_dictionary:
            task = task_dictionary[count]
            if 'Yes' == task['task_complete']:
                completed_tasks += 1
            elif 'No' == task['task_complete']:
                uncompleted_tasks += 1
            
            # Comparing the dates to check if the task is overdue.
            datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(task['date_due'], '%d %b %Y') # 'strptime()' parses a string representing a time according to a format.
            if datetime_object < datetime.datetime.today() and 'No' == task['task_complete']: # 'today()' method of date class under datetime module returns a date object which contains the value of Today's date.
                overdue_tasks += 1
                
        percentage_incomplete = (uncompleted_tasks * 100)/(len(task_dictionary))
        percentage_overdue = (overdue_tasks * 100)/(len(task_dictionary))

        # Print / write everything to the file.
        task_overview.write(f"Total number of tasks generated using Task Manager: {len(task_dictionary)}\n")
        task_overview.write(f"Number of completed tasks: {completed_tasks}\n")
        task_overview.write(f"Number of uncompleted tasks: {uncompleted_tasks}\n")
        task_overview.write(f"Number of uncompleted tasks that are overdue: {overdue_tasks:.0f}\n")
        task_overview.write(f"Percentage of uncompleted tasks: {percentage_incomplete:.0f}%\n")
        task_overview.write(f"Percentage of uncompleted overdue tasks: {percentage_overdue:.0f}%\n")
    
        print("Task_overview.txt written.")
```